# Manually Set UINavigationController Children

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have two children (a root child and a second child) in a navigation controller. I normally go to the root child then segue to the second child. This allows me to use the navigation controller buttons to go back to the root child (and the its state is the same as I left it).

Is there a way to manually set attributes on the root child, but start the navigation controller on the second child?

The way I'm currently doing it is setting the attributes on the root child then segueing to the second child but I don't want to have to wait for the root child controller to load and then wait for the segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate the two child view controllers, and configure their attributes as you wish, and then use:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to load them into the navigation controller.  See the [Apple Docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:):

> "Use this method to update or replace the current view controller stack without pushing or popping each controller explicitly. In addition, this method lets you update the set of controllers without animating the changes, which might be appropriate at launch time when you want to return the navigation controller to a previous state."